# Wind tunnel experiment that measures lift (not the lift coefficient)?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft, lift

Does anyone know of a wind tunnel experiment on a wing or airplane that measures the absolute amount of lift (not the lift coefficient); and demonstrates conclusively that the lift generate by a wing equals the weight of the aircraft (Lift = Weight).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the case of a typical wind tunnel containing a set of load cells that measure the forces on the model, the load cells are actually measuring the lift force, drag force, and moment about the center of lift. Those *forces* are then used to calculate the *coefficients*.

Comment: Great. Is there any report which provides the details of an experiment that I can access?

Comment: here is something to try. I went to engineering school at UC Davis in the 1970's. they had a wind tunnel with which lab classes were taught and we had to determine how to translate the load cell outputs into resolved forces and then derive the coefficients from them. You could try going on-line and looking for course descriptions which would describe the wind tunnel lab exercise.

Comment: The reports of experiments I found measured the upward force on a model aircraft tied down to the measuring equipment; and interpreted this as lift. But the reports never provide the wind speed, weight, ..... data. And none of these reports showed that Lift = Weight. Sorry, I should have been more precise in the question. The objective is to test the assumption that Lift = Weight for an airplane. Thanks.